# program ended prematurely and may have crashed. exit code 0xc0000005

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

Here is my code I want to multiply a 2D array with a vector array:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<mpi.h>
using namespace std;
int v_array[10] ;
int ch_size, start, close;
int res ;
int rows, cols;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pro_id, tot_pros;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pro_id); 
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &tot_pros); 

    if (pro_id == 0) {
        cout << "Enter rows and columns: ";
        cin >> rows >> cols;

        int **array = new int*[rows];
        int size1 = rows * cols;
        array[0] = new int[size1];
        for (int j = 1; j < rows; j++) {
            array[j] = &array[0][j*cols];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            v_array[i] = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                array[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < tot_pros; i++) {
            ch_size = (rows / (tot_pros - 1));
            start = (i - 1) * ch_size;
            if (((i + 1) == tot_pros) && ((rows % (tot_pros - 1)) != 0)) {
                close = rows;
            }
            else {
                close = start + ch_size;
            }
            MPI_Send(&start, 1, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&close, 1, MPI_INT, i, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&cols, 1, MPI_INT, i, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&array[start][0], ch_size *cols, MPI_INT, i, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
    else
     {
        int cols;
        MPI_Recv(&start, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        MPI_Recv(&close, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        MPI_Recv(&cols, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        int **array = new int*[(close - start)*cols];
        MPI_Recv(array, (close - start) *cols , MPI_INT, 0, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        for (int i = start; i < close; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                cout << array[i]<<array[j];
                    res += array[i][j] * v_array[i];
                    cout << res;
                }
            }
         }
    MPI_Finalize(); 
    return 0;
}
```

This same program is working fine when I have static array, But with dynamic I got this error.

> E:\MS(CS)\2nd Semester\Parallel
>   Programing\programs\arr_multi\Debug>mpiexec -n 4 arr_multi.exe Enter
>   rows and columns: 3 2
>
> job aborted: [ranks] message
>
> [0-1] terminated
>
> [2] process exited without calling finalize
>
> [3] terminated
>
> ---- error analysis -----
>
> [2] on RAMISHA-PC arr_multi.exe ended prematurely and may have
>   crashed. exit code 0xc0000005
>
> ---- error analysis -----

I declared an array with contiguous location and my rows are divided correctly among processes. I think I have problem with my data structure and tried many solutions but in vain.

Comment: When you used your debugger, what was line was the program on when it crashed?

Comment: I can't shake the feeling that what you send with `MPI_Send` is different from what you receive with `MPI_Recv`. Remember that `array` in both branches are an array of *pointers*, and generally you can't transmit pointers between processes (even if created from the same program).

Comment: Please don't paste a screenshot of text, paste the text itself

Comment: And when you used your debugger to execute your program, one line at a time, and examine the values of all variables on each step, what observations did you make?

Comment: On non root rank, should you access `array[i-start][j]` instead ? Your debug statement is also incorrect. Generally speaking, you should `MPI_Scatterv(array, ...)` and you do not need to transmit `start`, `close` nor `cols`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I have to observe performance through using multiple MPI commands. So first I have to do in this way

Comment: @Eljay I got this error when debugging `Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasadhlp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I cannot debug code after using MPI commands

Comment: @rustyx I have missed here but in actual program I have this

Comment: So? Simulate whatever those "MPI commands" do, whatever input and output they produce, then debug your code using simulated input and output.

Comment: Your screen snapshot is not very clear.  Please post the *text* output.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, there *are* ways to debug an MPI application, which should really be your top priority. A general approach for multi-process applications is to pause at the beginning of your application e.g. with a `getchar()` then attach to each process with a debugger as described [**here**](http://wiki.rac.manchester.ac.uk/community/MPI/VisualStudio_mpich2_howto):

> - compile, link and start running your MPI program (you may wish to put a `read` statement early on to hold the program while you do the next steps)
> - attach to one of the currently running MPI processes: *Debug* - *Attach to Process* brings up a dialogue box which lists Available Processes. You should see `NUM` instances (where `N` is from `mpiexec -n NUM`) of your executable. Select all of these and click on *Attach*. You can now debug by adding breakpoints etc. To move between MPI processes use the Process drop-down menu just above the code listing.

Having said that, at least one of the problems is with this part: `int **array = new int*[(close - start)*cols];` (in the receive part of the application). You allocate the first dimension but not the second, so all pointers in the first dimension are uninitialized.

Change it to something like:

```
        int *array = new int[(close - start) * cols];
        MPI_Recv(array, (close - start) *cols, MPI_INT, 0, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        for (int i = start; i < close; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                cout << array[(i - start) * cols];
                res += array[(i - start) * cols] * v_array[i];
                cout << res;
            }
        }
        delete[] array;
```

Or if you really want to use a 2D array, copy the initialization code from the sending part:

```
        int rows = close - start;
        int **array = new int*[rows];
        int size1 = rows * cols;
        array[0] = new int[size1];
        for (int j = 1; j < rows; j++) {
            array[j] = &array[0][j*cols];
        }
```

The second problem is that `v_array`, being a global is not initialized in your receiver processes. Remember that in MPI each process is an independent program. So you should initialize `v_array` always, i.e. regardless of `pro_id`.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            v_array[i] = 1;
        }
```

Comment: But this will declare 1D array. I have to use 2D array.

Comment: I have updated my code as you guide me but still same result.`E:\MS(CS)\2nd Semester\Parallel Programing\programs\arr_multi\Debug>mpiexec -n 4 arr_multi.exe
Enter rows and columns: 3
2

-842150451
-842150451

job aborted:
[ranks] message

[0-2] terminated

[3] process exited without calling finalize

---- error analysis -----

[3] on RAMISHA-PC
arr_multi.exe ended prematurely and may have crashed. exit code 0xc0000005

---- error analysis -----`

Comment: Try to [debug](http://wiki.rac.manchester.ac.uk/community/MPI/VisualStudio_mpich2_howto) it. `-842150451` is `0xCDCDCD` - meaning you read deleted memory.